# How to delete a line which has a blank line just after it?

Tags: python-3.x, file, delete-row

I have a file which I read and make some actions.

```
export_comp_f = open(env_path +  '/girobo2/sim_export/modelsim/compile.do', 'r')
exp_cont = export_comp_f.readlines()
exp_cont = list(filter(lambda x: 'work/hdl' not in x, exp_cont)) 
exp_cont = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r"^\".*?(\/2016\.2)", r'"$vivado_path/2016.2', x), exp_cont))
exp_cont = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r"\+.*?(\/girobo2)", r'+incdir+$env_path/girobo2', x), exp_cont))
exp_cont = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r"\"\w\:.*?(\/girobo2)", r'"$env_path/girobo2', x), exp_cont))
exp_cont = exp_cont[:-5]
exp_cont.append('vlog -work xil_defaultlib "glbl.v"\n')
export_comp_f.close()
```

I want to delete any line which contains begin with "vcom" and  has a blank line just after it.

For example:

```
**vcom -work lib_pkg_v1_0_2 -64 -93 \**  //should be deleted


vcom -work lib_fifo_v1_0_5 -64 -93 \
"$env_path/girobo2/syn/syn.ip_user_files/ipstatic/lib_fifo_v1_0/hdl/src/vhdl/async_fifo_fg.vhd" \
"$env_path/girobo2/syn/syn.ip_user_files/ipstatic/lib_fifo_v1_0/hdl/src/vhdl/sync_fifo_fg.vhd" \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
line = ['vcom -work lib_pkg_v1_0_2 -64 -93 \  //should be deleted',
'',
'',
'vcom -work lib_fifo_v1_0_5 -64 -93 ',
'"$env_path/girobo2/syn/syn.ip_user_files/ipstatic/lib_fifo_v1_0/hdl/src/vhdl/async_fifo_fg.vhd" ',
'"$env_path/girobo2/syn/syn.ip_user_files/ipstatic/lib_fifo_v1_0/hdl/src/vhdl/sync_fifo_fg.vhd" ']

output = []
for i in range(len(line) - 1):
    if line[i][:4] == "vcom" and line[i + 1].strip() == "":
        pass
    else:
        output.append(line[i])

print(output)
```

If you prefer to modify the original `line`, the code becomes shorter.

```
for i in range(len(line) - 1):
    if line[i][:4] == "vcom" and line[i + 1].strip() == "":
        line[i] = None

line = [item for item in line if item is not None]
print(line)
```

Comment: I prefer not to create another list, but to delete the vcom line from the origin list.

Comment: If you prefer to modify the original line, the code becomes shorter. Check the edited answer.

Comment: instead of `line[i] = None` I just can do `del line[i]`

Comment: No, you can't. If you `del line[i]` twice or more in `for` loop, the code will cause `IndexError: list index out of range` because the length of list will decrease during a loop. Test for yourself by `line = ['vcom...', '', 'vcom2...', '', 'env...', 'env...']`. You should first mark the elements to delete and then delete them after the loop ends.

Comment: I wrote in the range `range(len(line) - 2):`, and use `del` (I know that there is no line to delete in the end of the file).

Comment: Still no. If `'vcom'` found three times or more, index error occurs. Test for yourself. `line = ['vcom...', '', 'vcom...', '', 'env...', 'env...', 'vcom...', '']`.